# Set field form value from view

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

How to add field value manually from view?

model.py

```
class Connect(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    conft = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username)
```

form.py

```
class NacmForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,required = False)
    conft = forms.Textarea()
    class Meta:
        model = Connect
        fields = ['username', 'password','conft']

    labels = {'conft':_('Config'),}
```

view.py

```
class config_static(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formm = NacmForm(request.POST or None)
        ipform = IpFormset(request.POST)
        userValue = formm['username'].value()
        passValue = formm['password'].value()

        if ipform.is_valid() and formm.is_valid():
            simpanForm = formm.save()

            for form in ipform:
                ipaddr = form.cleaned_data.get('ipaddr')
                vendor = form.cleaned_data.get('vendor')
                                .......
                                //some code//
                                .......          
                simpanIp = form.save(commit=False)
                simpanIp.connect_id = simpanForm
                simpanIp.save()
                simpanForm.save()

            .........
            //some code//
```

i want to set "conft" value manually, maybe like

```
configuration = "some config"
conft = configuration
```

i already tried

```
configuration = "some config"
NacmForm(initial={'conft': configuration })

or

formm.fields['conft'].initial = configuration 

or

formm = NacmForm(request.POST, initial={"conft": configuration })
```

when i use that code above, the value isnt save to database, then i tried this

```
Connect.objects.create(conft=configuration)
```

its save to database but not in same row

Comment: or how about make "Connect.objects.create(conft=configuration)" to become one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after googling, i just add this line

```
class config_static(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formm = NacmForm(request.POST or None)
        ipform = IpFormset(request.POST)
        userValue = formm['username'].value()
        passValue = formm['password'].value()

        if ipform.is_valid() and formm.is_valid():
            # If both form is valid
            simpanForm = formm.save()

            for form in ipform:
                ipaddr = form.cleaned_data.get('ipaddr')
                vendor = form.cleaned_data.get('vendor')
                                .......
                                //some code//
                                .......    
                simpanForm.conft = "ip route configuration" #  i add this   
                simpanIp = form.save(commit=False)
                simpanIp.connect_id = simpanForm
                simpanIp.save()
                simpanForm.save()

            .........
            //some code//
```

Answer (score 1):

`formm.cleaned_data` returns dictionary. So, you can add/update/remove `keys` manually. `initial={}` This is for rendering purposes (Which adds in html forms `initial` values `value="something"`). As far as i understand you want to modify incoming data when `HTTP POST` is made. Try like this.

```
class config_static(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formm = NacmForm(request.POST or None)
        ipform = IpFormset(request.POST)
        userValue = formm['username'].value()
        passValue = formm['password'].value()

        if ipform.is_valid() and formm.is_valid():
            # If both form is valid
            formm.cleaned_data['conft'] = '<new_value>' # + this is added logic
            simpanForm = formm.save()

            for form in ipform:
                ipaddr = form.cleaned_data.get('ipaddr')
                vendor = form.cleaned_data.get('vendor')
                                .......
                                //some code//
                                .......          
                simpanIp = form.save(commit=False)
                simpanIp.connect_id = simpanForm
                simpanIp.save()
                simpanForm.save()

            .........
            //some code//
```

## forms.py

```
class NacmForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,required = False)
    # conft = forms.Textarea()
    class Meta:
        model = Connect
        fields = ['username', 'password','conft']

    labels = {'conft':_('Config'),}
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: conft still not save to database

Comment: I updated answer. remove `conft = forms.TextArea()` from `NacmForm` class. `ipform.is_valid() and formm.is_valid() # If this returns True it will be saved.`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but still not save to database

Comment: Your forms makes validations ? `formm.save() # is this line of code executed ?` If your `Forms` does not make validations it will not be saved. try to print something inside `if ipform.is_valid() and formm.is_valid(): print('forms are valid')`...

Comment: yes, add line code print ('form are valid') and its show 'form are valid' in console

Comment: `IpFormset` Show us this class.